# How to show images of one site to another site

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having two site related to shopping. My requirement is when I insert any product on that site that product also be reflected on the second site.

- one site is: http://www.mcfloresca.com/
- second site: http://www.etsy.com/shop/oneofakindclothing?ref=top_trail

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data (image, text, whatever) to be the same in both sites, then you must either be able to access Etsy.com's database (which I believe you can't) or use an API.

Etsy does have an API here: [Etsy Developer Community](http://developer.etsy.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to embed images from one site into another? Do you have permission to do so?

Otherwise, it's just a matter of having on site1:

```
<img src="http://site2.example.com/somepicture.jpg" />
```

If you mean you want product information shared between the two, then you'd either have to have both sites backed by the same database, or some method of syncrhonizing the databases on each site. YOu don't say which database you're on, but since you've tagged the question with php/wordpress, I'm guessing MySQL. For synchronizing two different MySQL installs, look up [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) setups in the MySQL docs

Oh, and saying it's urgent isn't a good way to ask questions here. If it's urgent, then go find a local guru you can pay..

Comment: I think the OP wants to "access a database" of site1 in site2. So whenever she adds an item, it would show up in both sites.